# Linq to XML query problem

Tags: linq-to-xml

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<AddressValidateResponse>
  <Address ID="0">
    <FirmName>FIRM NAME, INC</FirmName> 
    <Address2>123 MAIN ST</Address2> 
    <City>SOME PLACE</City> 
    <State>CA</State> 
    <Zip5>90028</Zip5> 
    <Zip4>1467</Zip4> 
  </Address>
  <Address ID="1">
    <Error>
      <Number>-2147219401</Number> 
      <Source>SOURCE INFO HERE</Source> 
      <Description>Address Not Found.</Description> 
      <HelpFile /> 
      <HelpContext>1000440</HelpContext> 
    </Error>
  </Address>
  <Address ID="2">
    <FirmName>FIRM NAME, INC</FirmName> 
    <Address2>123 MAIN ST</Address2> 
    <City>SOME PLACE</City> 
    <State>CA</State> 
    <Zip5>90028</Zip5> 
    <Zip4>1467</Zip4> 
  </Address>
  <Address ID="3">
     <FirmName>FIRM NAME, INC</FirmName> 
     <Address2>123 MAIN ST</Address2> 
     <City>SOME PLACE</City> 
     <State>CA</State> 
     <Zip5>90028</Zip5> 
     <Zip4>1467</Zip4> 
  </Address>
  <Address ID="4">
    <Error>
      <Number>-2147219401</Number> 
      <Source>SOURCE INFO HERE</Source> 
      <Description>Address Not Found.</Description> 
      <HelpFile /> 
      <HelpContext>1000440</HelpContext> 
    </Error>
  </Address>
</AddressValidateResponse>
```

I need to create two lists. One with valid addresses and one with the errors blocks. In the above example, the first list would contain 3 addresses and the second list would contain two. Not sure how filter query properly. Thanks.

I was able to get it to work with the following but I suspect there is a more efficient way to do the same thing:

```
    var errors = from d in xDoc.Descendants("Address")
                         from e in d.Elements("Error")
                         where e.Element("Description").Value.Trim().ToUpper().Contains("ADDRESS NOT FOUND")
                         select new AddressObject
                         {
                             Order = (int)d.Attribute("ID"),
                             StreetAddress = "NO MATCH FOUND",
                             OtherAddress = String.Empty,
                             City = String.Empty,
                             State = String.Empty,
                             ZipCode = String.Empty,
                             ZipPlus4 = String.Empty
                         };

            errorList = errors.ToList();

    var addresses = from a in xDoc.Descendants("Address")
                        from b in a.Elements("FirmName")
                        where b.Value != String.Empty
                        select new AddressObject
                        {
                            Order = (int)a.Attribute("ID"),
                            StreetAddress = (string)a.Element("Address2") ?? String.Empty,
                            OtherAddress = (string)a.Element("Address1") ?? String.Empty,
                            City = (string)a.Element("City") ?? String.Empty,
                            State = (string)a.Element("State") ?? String.Empty,
                            ZipCode = (string)a.Element("Zip5") ?? String.Empty,
                            ZipPlus4 = (string)a.Element("Zip4") ?? String.Empty
                        };

    validList = addressess.ToList();
```

Comment: I am using c# per my edits above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this - seems there ought to be a more efficient way, but I can't figure it out right now...

```
string xmlContent = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" ?> 
<AddressValidateResponse>
  <Address ID=""0"">
    <FirmName>FIRM NAME, INC</FirmName> 
    <Address2>123 MAIN ST</Address2> 
    <City>SOME PLACE</City> 
    <State>CA</State> 
    <Zip5>90028</Zip5> 
    <Zip4>1467</Zip4> 
  </Address>
  <Address ID=""1"">
    <Error>
      <Number>-2147219401</Number> 
      <Source>SOURCE INFO HERE</Source> 
      <Description>Address Not Found.</Description> 
      <HelpFile /> 
      <HelpContext>1000440</HelpContext> 
    </Error>
  </Address>
  <Address ID=""2"">
    <FirmName>FIRM NAME, INC</FirmName> 
    <Address2>123 MAIN ST</Address2> 
    <City>SOME PLACE</City> 
    <State>CA</State> 
    <Zip5>90028</Zip5> 
    <Zip4>1467</Zip4> 
  </Address>
  <Address ID=""3"">
     <FirmName>FIRM NAME, INC</FirmName> 
     <Address2>123 MAIN ST</Address2> 
     <City>SOME PLACE</City> 
     <State>CA</State> 
     <Zip5>90028</Zip5> 
     <Zip4>1467</Zip4> 
  </Address>
  <Address ID=""4"">
    <Error>
      <Number>-2147219401</Number> 
      <Source>SOURCE INFO HERE</Source> 
      <Description>Address Not Found.</Description> 
      <HelpFile /> 
      <HelpContext>1000440</HelpContext> 
    </Error>
  </Address>
</AddressValidateResponse>";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlContent);

var errors = doc.Descendants("Address").Where(a => a.Descendants("Error").Count() > 0).ToList();
var real = doc.Descendants("Address").Where(a => a.Descendants("Error").Count() == 0).ToList();
```

Basically, you check for each `<Address>` XElement how many sub-elements with a name of `Error` it contains - 0 means a "real" address, > 0 means an error entry.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to tweak your suggestion and accomplish the same thing.